# Present a view with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiview, animated

Instead of doing `self.view = view;` like I am currently I want to present this view with animation. It is not an entire view controller but just a view, I am just replacing the current view with this view on a button click.

Is there anyway to do this *animated*?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UIView *newView = ...;
// new view is added as a subview somewhere

newView.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
    newView.alpha = 1;
}];
```

Which will fade the view in. You could also look at `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` which provides other animation options. Or `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this but slide in? Like a segue in a storyboard.

Comment: sure, you can set the initial frame to off screen (where the alpha is set to 0 above) and in the animation block set the frame to the final position on screen (where the alpha is set to 1 above).

Comment: Ah... using `view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);` then `view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);` Something like that?

Comment: That seemed to work, where should I add the stuff to the view, the labels and buttons are appearing before the animation is complete.

Comment: Setting the frame size to 0, 0 you need to be a little careful as the auto-resizing / auto-layout rules will come into play so you need to ensure they're right. You may also need to set `clipsToBounds` on the view to prevent subviews from drawing outside of its bounds.

Comment: And where do i add components, such as labels and buttons, it appears that those are being put on the screen before the view fully appears.

Comment: You must already have them as subviews of your new view. That's where `clipsToBounds` comes in as it will prevent them from appearing as the new view animates in.

Comment: Throwing in a `view.clipsToBounds = YES;` before the animation seems to make it look smoother, thanks a lot.